# Firebase Dynamic Link to pass though UTM parameters appended to the short link

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I was using Firebase Dynamic Link to create a short link manualy and notice that the UTM parameters added to that short link got removed when firebase generated the deep link url:

short link:

https://lapakgok.page.link/c2Sd

dynamic link:

https://www.lapakgok.com/products/item.html?id=10035

but when the short link has an extra UTM parameters :
https://lapakgok.page.link/c2Sd?utm_source=google

the utm_source=google doesn't gets appended into the dynamic link, it's still
https://www.lapakgok.com/products/item.html?id=10035

instead of

https://www.lapakgok.com/products/item.html?id=10035&utm_source=google

the utm_source=google doesn't gets appended into the dynamic link, it's still
https://www.lapakgok.com/products/item.html?id=10035

instead of

https://www.lapakgok.com/products/item.html?id=10035&utm_source=google